# Time Difference with UTC java

Tags: java, android, date, time

I want convert the Date in long. But the hours are incorrectly calculated at pc. On Android emulator is the Time correct calculated(on emulator is UTC time). Please help

```
String time = "15:54";

Date date = new Date();
date.setHours(Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)));

long Hours = (date.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

System.out.print(Hours);                        // 14
System.out.print("\n" + date.getHours());       // 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting the hours to `Date`, `java.util.Date` object is independent of the concept of `TimeZone`. Per its javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html),

> Although the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal
>   time (UTC), it may not do so exactly, depending on the host
>   environment of the Java Virtual Machine.

Hence, when you set your hours to 15, date interprets your own timezone and sets the hours to it. If there is a difference in `UTC` (the result you expect) and your current timezone, that difference is being reflected in your case above (14 vs 15).

To solve it, 1 option is to explicitly bring your own timezone to UTC and match the expected results:

```
String time = "15:54";

Date date = new Date();
java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // ADDED THIS LINE
date.setHours(Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)));

long hours = (date.getTime() / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24;

System.out.print(hours); // NOW THIS GIVES 15
System.out.print("\n" + date.getHours()); // 15
```

The other option would to use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class (if not [jodatime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)) in case you want to accurately interpret the `TimeZone` related results.

Comment: Be aware that changing the default time zone is risky. Affects the entire JVM, all the software running in that JVM will get a different time zone. I would not recommend that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

This kind of date-time work is much easier with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Relying on the default time zone is troublesome. Instead, specify your time zone. It sounds like in your case the desired hour "15" is in UTC/GMT (no time zone offset). So, specify UTC.

What did you mean by "convert the Date in long"? Perhaps you meant get the milliseconds-since-epoch stored inside the Date (and in Joda-Time DateTime).

```
DateTime now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime fifteen = now.withHourOfDay( 15 );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "fifteen: " + fifteen );
System.out.println( "fifteen in millis: " + fifteen.getMillis() );
System.out.println( "fifteen's hour-of-day: " + fifteen.getHourOfDay() );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-14T12:43:00.836Z
fifteen: 2014-02-14T15:43:00.836Z
fifteen in millis: 1392392580836
fifteen's hour-of-day: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

If try to call method:

```
private static String   TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm Z";

public static void TestDate( String time_ ) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat    format  = new SimpleDateFormat( TIME_FORMAT );
    Date                date    = format.parse( time_ );
    long                hours   = (date.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

    System.out.println( "The value 'hours' for '" + time_ + "' is '" + Long.toString( hours ) + "'" );

}
```

with "15:54 UTC", output wil be:

```
The value 'hours' for '15:54 UTC' is '15'
```